# ListView doesn't apear in Emulator AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-emulator, adapter

I am new to Android Studio; I am following a tuto, and I am trying to execute the following code. The execution doesn't report any bug; however, the ListView did not show in the emulator.
Could you please inform me how can I fix this issue?

My main activity file is:
SelectionMultipleActivity.java

```
package com.example.tutolist;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SelectionMultipleActivity extends Activity {
    
    private ListView mListSexe = null;

    private Button mSend = null;


    private String[] mSexes = {"Masculin", "Feminin"};

    private String[] mLangages = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListSexe =  findViewById(R.id.listSexe);
        mSend =  findViewById(R.id.send);
        mLangages = new String[]{"C", "Java", "COBOL", "Perl"};
        mListSexe.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, mSexes));
    
        mListSexe.setItemChecked(0, true);


        mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(SelectionMultipleActivity.this, "Merci ! Les données ont été envoyées !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           
                mListSexe.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
           
                mListSexe.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SelectionMultipleActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mSexes));

            
                mSend.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My layout file is:
activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSexe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/quel_est_votre_sexe" />


    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
    />
    <!-- On choisit le mode de sélection avec android:choiceMode -->


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listSexe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"></ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Envoyer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get the following
[image]

Comment: ListView needs a known Height. Try using "200dp" instead of "wrap_content"

Comment: Can you provide the code of your adapter?

Comment: @emandt it does not show even with known height.

Comment: @MaximeClaude, I am not implementing any adapter. I am using the bit-in adapter provided by android studio

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the correct `layout` for each list item.

Try `mListSexe.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mSexes));` Instead.